# NSRange array of odd or even count

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsrange

I have an array of 977 of data, I've been trying to split it to 20 section in `UITableView` but i cannot get it correct, i am trying to do it dynamically. like if i got an array of 312 or 32 or 545 the equation should divide it, and add the last odd elements in array, I'm placing the new data in array of arrays.

So here is what I'm doing :

```
var dataof977 = Mydata()
var mutA  = NSMutableArray()

        for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++)
        {
            var halfArray : NSArray!
            var theRange = NSRange()

            theRange.location = i*19;
            theRange.length = dataof977.afa.count / 19
            halfArray = dataof977.afa.subarrayWithRange(theRange)
            mutA.addObject(halfArray)
        }
```

**Note :** `dataof977` is reference of class and `afa` is a String array.

What am i missing here ?s

Comment: It is not clear what kind of data `Mydata()` produces. You have to explain your cryptic variable names, such as `afa` and the like.

Comment: Your `location` variable needs to also be based upon the length of the new subarrays.  Your location on each iteration is 0, 19, 38, ... no matter what the length of the original array is.  Instead, `location` needs to be `i * newsubarraylen`.

Comment: @vacawama , but sometimes its not gonna be even number ? how do i need to do it ?

Comment: You need to decide how you want to divide them up.  For instance, how do you want to divide 7 items into 20 sections? Do the first 19 sections get 0, and section 20 get 7 OR do the first 7 sections get 1 and the next 13 sections get 0.  How about 23 items?  Do the first 3 sections get 2 and then the rest 1 or do the first 19 sections get 1 and the last get 4?

Comment: i think the lowest array i can get is over 35 items, so it shouldn't make a huge problem. I'm just trying calculate and divide dynamically which really took so much time from me. @vacawama.

Comment: Do you mind in the last section is much smaller or larger than the first 19, or do you want them to be all within 1 in size of each other?

Comment: The last section array could be less than 20, maybe 4 items or 3. and the rest is 20 items or whatever. the important that it divides the first sections equally and the last section to put the rest of it. @vacawama

Comment: For instance, 35 is going to have to be 19 sections of 1 and one section of 16.  If you make your size 2, you only have 17 sections of 2 and 1 of 1, and then 2 more empty sections.  I thought you might want the first 15 sections to have 2 and then the last have 1 each.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91296/discussion-between-aaoii-and-vacawama).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

1. You need to start each `location` where the previous left off.  To do this, introduce a `location` variable to keep track of where you are in the original array.
2. Some of your sections will need more items since your `count` might not be a multiple of 20.  I think your best best is to give the first `n` sections an extra item to make up for the leftovers.
3. Your loop needs to iterate 20 times, not 19.  I have changed it to use `for in` which is better Swift style.

---

```
var mutA  = NSMutableArray()

let sublength = dataof977.afa.count / 20
let leftovers = dataof977.afa.count % 20

// location of each new subarray    
var location = 0

for i in 0..<20
{
    var length = sublength

    // The first sections will have 1 more each
    if i < leftovers {
        length++
    }

    let theRange = NSMakeRange(location, length)

    let halfArray = dataof977.afa.subarrayWithRange(theRange)
    mutA.addObject(halfArray)

    // move location up past the items we just added
    location += length
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the possibility to work with Swift arrays instead of NSArray, you can use `stride` to iterate by steps and divide an array in equal parts with the remainder elements in the last array:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

extension Array {
    func splitBy(subSize: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return 0.stride(to: self.count, by: subSize).map { startIndex in
            let endIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(subSize, limit: self.count)
            return Array(self[startIndex ..< endIndex])
        }
    }
}

let chunks = arr.splitBy(5)

print(chunks) // [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

*Note: this is for Swift 2.*

Answer (score 0):

You are only doing 19 iterations, not 20.

```
for var i = 0; i < 20; i++
```

You are taking one 19th of the data count, not one 20th. You are repeating the length calculation 19 times in the loop, which is redundant.

It would be easier to dispense with `NSRange`. Just iterate though all array elements, keep a counter up to the pre-calculate subarray size, and once it reaches the critical number, reset it to zero and start a new subarray to add to your result array.

This will presumably perform better if you use Swift arrays, but this is not strictly necessary.

Comment: but even with that, my last index after the iteration is 431 not 977, so there is something wrong !